# How to get perfect collision between 2 sprite in cocos 2D

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have 2 sprite. for collide i use bounding box. But its not perfect collision. its collide with transparent image also. i need perfect collision.

Suppose i have :

```
             CCSprite *sprite1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"image.png"];
             CCSprite *sprite2 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"image.png"];

             if (CGRectIntersectsRect([sprite1 boundingBox], [sprite2 boundingBox]))
             {
                  // Collision Detected ....
             }
```

But its create a prob . its collide but not perfectly collide.
 anybody can help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: good to use box2d physics shape instead of pixel perfect bit-wise checking.

Answer (score -1):

```
    CCSprite *player = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"image.png"];
    [self addChild:player];

    CCSprite *enemy = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"image.png"];
    [self addChild:enemy];


    float pos_x = player.position.x  - enemy.position.x;
    float pos_y = player.position.y  - enemy.position.y;

    float pos_xy = (pos_x * pos_x) + (pos_y * pos_y);
    float Collision = (10+5) * (10+5); // Let 10 be the radious of player & 5 be the radious of enemy

    if (pos_xy <= Collision)
    {
        // Collision Detected
    }
   // But its is only for round shaped image .  like: Ball.
   And its create perfect collision using pythagorean Theorm
```